# Remover eventos da fila de mensagens

Tags: ios, objective-c, eventos, iphone, gui

Como eu posso evitar que minha classe (UIView) receba um evento de toque quando ainda houver eventos do mesmo tipo na fila de mensagens?

Comment: Que fila de mensagens são estas que você se refere?

Comment: Você poderia explicar melhor o que você deseja?

Comment: É a fila de eventos da thread principal. Você pode associar uma fila de eventos para uma thread (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/MainEventLoop.html). Eu quero cancelar o processamento de um evento de toque (UIControlEventTouchDragInside, para ser mais exato) caso este evento já tenha ocorrido, mas não tenha sido processado ainda.

Comment: @FilipeBeck Por que você precisa cancelar o processamento de um evento de toque?

Comment: Eu estou trabalhando em um aplicativo de gravação musical. Em algumas telas eu tenho um seletor de categorias (percussão, cordas, teclado...), um seletor de instrumentos (guitarra elétrica, piano...) relacionado com a categoria selecionada, e uma lista de trilhas relacionada com o instrumento selecionado. Esta lista é recuperada de um servidor remoto. Quando eu seleciono uma nova categoria, o seletor de instrumentos muda para os itens da nova categoria.

Comment: Esta mudança é animada, e no final da animação eu envio o evento UIControlEventValueChanged (escrevi errado no comentário acima), que será recebido e processado pelo controlador, que exibirá a nova lista. O problema é que este evento estava sendo enviado duas vezes consecutivas na inicialização. Eu já encontrei o lugar onde isso acontece. Agora preciso modificar de forma que não altere o comportamento em outras telas que usem a mesma classe.

Comment: posta o código, para tentar ajudar.